# Mac OSX: restart required after removing auto mount

Tags: macos, mac, mount, unmount

By default `/home` directory is protected in mac osx and you need to remove the auto mount by editing the file `/etc/auto_master` and replace the following line

```
/home                   auto_home       -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
```

with this

```
#/home                   auto_home       -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
```

But after that you must restart the system like an old fashion windows :( to apply those changes. Is there any way to avoid restarting of system because it's really cumbersome and frustrating specially when you are in between of something very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some googling I found the command which will do the particular stuff I wanted. Assuming that the instructions in above question is being followed to remove auto mount for `/home` directory, issuing the following command does not require rebooting of machine:

```
sudo automount -vc
```

Hope that'll be useful for someone else like me. :)